# Prove that $\nabla_X tr(X^TB)= B $ where $B \in \mathbb{C^{m*n}}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R^{m*n}} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, trace

Prove that $\nabla_X tr(X^TB)= B $  where $B \in \mathbb{C^{m*n}}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R^{m*n}}  $  and $\nabla_X$ is the derivative with respect to X.

How can I prove the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, replace the trace with the Frobenius product, then take its differential to get
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= {\rm tr}(X^TB) \cr
   &= B:\!X \cr \cr
df &= B:dX \cr
   &= \bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial X}\bigg):dX \cr
} $$
Which means that the derivative must be 
$$ \eqalign {
  \frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= B \cr
} $$